# Reference to named theorem

Tags: article-writing

Assume Theorem 1 is Pythagoras' theorem, I want to reference it and I want to be nice to the reader and tell them at the point of reference both that I'm referring to the Pythagoras' theorem as well as where they can find it. What is the most common way to write such a reference reference? A few attempts of mine, none of which I am particularly fond of:

- Pythagoras' theorem (Theorem 1)
- Theorem 1 (Pythagoras)
- Pythagoras' Theorem 1

Just to be clear, the full sentence for the first case would read something like "This is a reference to Pythagoras theorem (Theorem 1)."

Comment: If you're referencing Theorem 1 in Pythagoras's paper, I like a good old "Theorem 1 in [Py]". If Theorem 1 of *your* paper is a result you'd like to attribute to Pythagoras, I like the second option you provided.